# How to move a subview to front and have existing view shift up to make room?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview that takes up the whole screen. Once the user clicks a cell and does stuff in the detail view, they are sent back to the first collectionview screen. At this point, I am bringing a view to the front that is a pseudo-tabbar. I want to shift the collection view up to accommodate this new view. Right now, it is just blocking the bottom row of collectionview cells. Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be show the code you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the pseudo-tab bar in the initial view and constrain your collection view's bottom to the top of the tab bar.
2. Set the tab bar's initial height to 0. Don't just set it to `hidden`, because that keeps the view's original height.
3. When the user returns to the collection view, set the tab bar's height to the desired value. Animating it in will look even better.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't have a height hard-coded in, just the aspect ratio, so the bar can grow with bigger screen sizes. Any way to do this programmatically? Thanks!